# Calling WriteConsole through an intermediate function does not work properly

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly, masm32

I'm trying to learn `assembly`, so I'm *manually* converting `C` and `C++` code to `assembly` code.

## Environment

- x86
- Visual Studio

## Goal

Manually converting the following `C` code to `assembly` code:

```
static HANDLE OUTPUT_HANDLE;

BOOL __stdcall InputConsole(const VOID *lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfCharsToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten)
{
    WriteConsoleA(OUTPUT_HANDLE, lpBuffer, nNumberOfCharsToWrite, lpNumberOfCharsWritten, 0);
}

int main()
{
    DWORD charsWritten;
    OUTPUT_HANDLE = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);


    InputConsole("Hello World!\n", 13, &charsWritten);
}
```

## Attempt

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

EXTRN   ExitProcess@4       :   PROC
EXTRN   GetStdHandle@4      :   PROC
EXTRN   WriteConsoleA@20    :   PROC

.data
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE       DD  ?
    WRITE_CONSOLE_STRING    DB  "Hello World!", 10, 0
    CHARS_WRITTEN           DD  ?

.code

WriteConsole PROC   
    PUSH    0                   ; lpReserved

    MOV     EAX, [ESP + 16]     ; lpNumberOfCharsWritten
    PUSH    EAX

    MOV     EAX, [ESP + 16]     ; nNumberOfCharsToWrite
    PUSH    EAX

    MOV     EAX, [ESP + 16]     ; lpBuffer
    PUSH    EAX

    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   ; hConsoleOutput

    CALL    WriteConsoleA@20

    ADD     ESP, 12             ; Restore stack

    RET
WriteConsole ENDP

main: NOP
    PUSH    -11
    CALL    GetStdHandle@4;
    MOV     STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, EAX

    LEA     EAX, CHARS_WRITTEN
    PUSH    EAX

    PUSH    13

    LEA     EAX, WRITE_CONSOLE_STRING
    PUSH    EAX

    CALL    WriteConsole

    PUSH    0
    CALL    ExitProcess@4
END main
```

## Problem

As of now it does print the actual line, however an `Access Violation Exception` is thrown at `ADD ESP, 12`. After closer inspection with the debugger it seems that I should be adding `16` instead of `12` to ESP to restore the stack. Still after making it `16` it freezes the application after it returns from the `procedure`.

## Questions

- How come I need to add `16` instead of `12` while I'm only pushing three 4-byte arguments on the stack?
- Is accessing the 'input arguments' using `ESP + xx` a proper way?
- Why does my program freeze, even though I'm restoring the stack and something is actually written on the console?
- Is there another way to 'pass argument by reference' in `assembly` instead of using a global `.data` address?

## Side note

I do know that you can set arguments for a procedure within Visual Studio (which is the IDE I'm using), however it should be possible with how I'm doing it, right?

Comment: `WriteConsoleA` will remove the arguments from the stack by itself, so try removing `ADD ESP, 12`.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm aware of that but I need to remove the arguments that are given to my custom procedure from the stack too. Because I'm following the __stdcall

Comment: You don't do that with `add esp` you do that by `ret 12`.

Comment: `InputConsole` takes 3 arguments, so the amount is 4 * 3 = 12. `RET imm16` instruction is useful to "return and add `imm16` to `ESP`".

Comment: Also note that `ret 12` pulls the return address **first** and only then adds the `12` which is what you need.

Comment: Thanks the `RET 12` does appear to do what it is supposed to do and now it does properly restore the stack. @Jester does that explain why through debugging I thought it needed to be 16?

Comment: The total is 16, yes, 4 bytes for the return address and 12 for the arguments. But the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do that with `add esp` you do that by `ret 12`.
                    – Jester